# DB2 Unique Constraint over multiple Columns

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to create a unique constraint over multiple columns like in Mysql?

```
UNIQUE KEY `uniqueKey` (`Field1`,`Field2`),
```

The only thing i have found is the unique keyword directly after the field.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `create unique index on table_name (column1, column2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add a unique constraint as:

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT unq_field1_field2 UNIQUE(field1, field2)
```

As with other databases, this is almost exactly equivalent to creating an index.  The difference is that the constraint is named -- which can be convenient for tracking constraints and understanding error messages.

Notice, that if the matching index does not exist, then a unique index is [automatically](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0055344.html) created.

Comment: Tried it! Works perfektly! Thank you!

Comment: Can we work around if one of the fields is nullable?

Comment: @valijon . . . Depends what you mean.  Unique constraints are allowed on nullable fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff db2 didn't let me create composite unique constraint because one of the fields was nullable.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a multi-column index

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex
                      ON mytable (col1, col2 desc, col3)
```