# DB2 -- unique constraint on multiple columns

Tags: db2

I'm trying to add a unique constraint on 2 columns on DB2-- `docType` column and `title` column. The values of each column can repeat in themselves. however, the values of (`docType`, `title`) pairs should not repeat.

I tried so far

```
ALTER TABLE externalfiles
ADD CONSTRAINT logicalKey UNIQUE (doctype, title)
```

and

```
alter table externalfiles add unique (doctype, title)
```

, and got the following error to both:

> Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table "PIT.EXTERNALFILES".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, DRIVER=4.21.29

Isn't this any allowed??

[DB2 Unique Constraint over multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619300/db2-unique-constraint-over-multiple-columns) suggests creating indexes as alternative to this. Haven't tried indexing them yet-- however, i'm wondering why the unique constraint isn't working.

TIA.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the error code in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

This [web search on db2 luw sqlstate 57016](https://www.google.com/search?q=db2+luw+sqlstate+57016) returns a number of links that suggest a prior ALTER may require that a REORG be performed before the ADD CONSTRAINT can be effected.

Perhaps most notable was the following doc link and snippet of text describing the RC7 [apparently SQLERRMC=7]:

[DB2 for Linux UNIX and Windows 9.7.0
->Database fundamentals
->Messages
->SQL Messages
->SQL0500 - SQL0999
->SQL0668N](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00668n.html)

> …
>   7 • The table is in the reorg pending state. This can occur after an
>   ALTER TABLE statement containing a REORG-recommended operation.
>   …

Answer (score 0):

First try to reorganize table by

```
call sysproc.admin_cmd ('reorg table <TABLE_NAME>');
```

Than try again to create unique index. It should work.